# MenuItem IsChecked from xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

is there a way to group my MenuItems so when one is set to IsCheck the previous one gets unchecked ?
I want a single IsChecked menu item.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same problem already has a solution on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/76c14163-9462-44d6-b0eb-6f22a006b423).

Comment: I am not. sure this is what I am looking for, all I need is a simple single check menu (as opposed to multiple selection menu)
I am using mvvm and I have a command on each menu item, but would like to control the check selection in the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

@archer - This only handles the case when the user clicks on an item, if the user uses a shortcut, a access key or navigates with the keyboard it will result in more than one checked item.

A good way will be to bind the IsChecked property of the MenuItems to your ViewModel (if you are using something like MVVM) and handle this behavior there.

Handling the Checked event, similarly to the example will deal with AccessKeys and keyboard navigation but not Shortcuts. Of course if you are not using commands, this will be fine.

EDIT: The code that @archer linked to is OK, a Click will be raised when the MenuItem is invoked, regardless of how it was done.